# java converting string to xml document

Tags: java

I have the string with text attribute containing the url. 
Here is the sample

```
<xml><body>
<TextView
width="wrap_content"
height="wrap_content"
text="http://www.hello.com/getpage.doappLinkName=checkworkflow&viewLinkName=na"
textColor="#000000"
textSize="14dp"
margin="0,6,0,0"
/>
</body></xml>
```

When i convert this string to xml document i get this exception java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol:

Here is the code

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();  
DocumentBuilder builder=docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlStr));
Document xmlDoc = builder.parse(is);
```

I think it's bcoz of url in text attribute. 
How can i convert this to xml document?

Comment: You must properly encode the & in your URL. (& characters are not allowed in XML attributes)

Comment: yeah correct but there will be many text attribute in my xml string. So to traverse that i need to convert into xml document and encode all the urls.

Comment: Do you use any Java library to parse the XML? Please [edit] your question and include the relevant parts of your code.

Comment: Talk to the producer of this XML and ask him to fix the XML entities.

Answer (score 1):

The ampersand (&) character is not allowed in xml. You must encode it as `&amp;`.

```
...getpage.doappLinkName=checkworkflow&viewLinkName...
```

becomes

```
...getpage.doappLinkName=checkworkflow&amp;viewLinkName...
```

Sample:

```
public void test() throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
    String xml = "<xml><body>\n"
            + "<TextView\n"
            + "width=\"wrap_content\"\n"
            + "height=\"wrap_content\"\n"
            + "text=\"http://www.hello.com/getpage.doappLinkName=checkworkflow&amp;viewLinkName=na\"\n"
            + "textColor=\"#000000\"\n"
            + "textSize=\"14dp\"\n"
            + "margin=\"0,6,0,0\"\n"
            + "/>\n"
            + "</body></xml>";
    DocumentBuilderFactory fctr = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder bldr = fctr.newDocumentBuilder();
    InputSource insrc = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));
    Document data = bldr.parse(insrc);
    System.out.println("data:" + data);
}
```

Comment: Yeah crct but to encode all the text attribute containing the url. I need to traverse all the text attribute of TextView element. For traversing i should convert the string to xml document